# Unexpected re-rendering of components

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to navigate back to a Menu component, but when I trigger a route to do so, the previous rendered Practice component is rendered in the root domain level, which should just be for the Menu component.

The solutions for similar questions on StackOverflow say to use `exact` in the route, but as you can see I have this in place.

How do I make this work as expected? Thanks.

Here's what I have...

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PracticeContextProvider from './contexts/PracticeContext';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './pages/Menu';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">      
      <PracticeContextProvider>
        <Menu />
      </PracticeContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Menu.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, useParams, useLocation, useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { PracticeContext } from '../contexts/PracticeContext';
import Practice from './Practice';
import ModuleLanguageSelector from '../components/ModuleLanguageSelector';
import ModuleListMenuItem from '../components/ModuleListMenuItem';

const Menu = () => {
  const { modulesJson } = useContext(PracticeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <ModuleLanguageSelector />
            { modulesJson && (
              modulesJson.map(module => {
                return (
                  <Link to={'/Practice/' + module._id} key={ module._id }>
                    <ModuleListMenuItem module={ module }></ModuleListMenuItem>
                  </Link>
                )
              })
            )}
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Practice/:moduleId" component={Practice} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );

}

export default Menu;
```

**Practice.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, useParams, useLocation, useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { PracticeContext } from '../contexts/PracticeContext';

import Menu from './Menu';

import ModulePracticeAnswerArea from '../components/ModulePracticeAnswerArea';
import ModulePracticeQuestion from '../components/ModulePracticeQuestion';
import ModulePracticeProgress from '../components/ModulePracticeProgress';
import ModulePracticeTutorial from '../components/ModulePracticeTutorial';

const Practice = () => {
  const { moduleId } = useParams();

  const { questionIndex } = useContext(PracticeContext);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="module-practice-screen">
        <h1>Practice</h1>
        <div className="module-practice-container">
          <Link to={'/'}>
            <button className="quit-practice">X</button>
          </Link>
          {
            moduleId ? 
              <React.Fragment>
                {/*<ModulePracticeTutorial moduleId={ moduleId } />*/} 
                <ModulePracticeProgress questionNumber={ questionIndex } /> 
                <ModulePracticeQuestion moduleId={ moduleId } questionNumber={ questionIndex } /> 
                <ModulePracticeAnswerArea moduleId={ moduleId } questionNumber={ questionIndex } /> 
              </React.Fragment>
            : 
              <h3>The menu should appear here!</h3>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Menu} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Practice;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need  `<Router>` and `<Switch>` in `Practice`

```
 const Practice = props => {
      const { moduleId } = useParams();
      const { questionIndex } = useContext(PracticeContext);

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="module-practice-screen">
            <h1>Practice</h1>
            <div className="module-practice-container">
              <Link to="/">
                <button>X</button>
              </Link>
              {moduleId ? (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {/*<ModulePracticeTutorial moduleId={ moduleId } />*/}
                  <ModulePracticeProgress questionNumber={questionIndex} />
                  <ModulePracticeQuestion
                    moduleId={moduleId}
                    questionNumber={questionIndex}
                  />
                  <ModulePracticeAnswerArea
                    moduleId={moduleId}
                    questionNumber={questionIndex}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              ) : (
                  <h3>The menu should appear here!</h3>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-framework-xydin)